# Cross-domain iframe cropping/div hiding? Or — alternative?

Tags: iframe

Here's our problem — we're at a loss.

On ourdomain.com, which is a Wordpress site, we need to embed part of a page at colleaguedomain.com. We'd like to not show the header and the footer (we only want the body). Our colleagues cannot edit any of their website on our behalf, so there is a cross-domain Same Origin Policy issue — however, our colleagues have given us explicit carte blanche to use any workarounds possible, so this is a technical issue not a moral one!

**Here is what we're doing currently:**

On ourdomain.com, we have an iframe inside a div with overflow:hidden. We set the position:absolute of the iframe with -px on top and left. This lets us hide the header. But we're struggling with also not displaying the footer. Is there any way we can hide the footer as well?

**We can't just use the iframe height to hide the footer,** because the part of the page in our iframe that we actually want to show is a form; when user clicks the next button javascript on the original page shows the next fields of the form. There are three "pages" of this form (remember, all in the iframe.) The last "page" is considerably longer (in height) than the first two. So if we set the height to accommodate the first two "pages", we can hide the header and the footer... but part of the last "page" of the form in the iframe will be hidden. If we accomodate that, the footer is shown on the first two pages.

Help? Can we hide the div of the footer in the iframe? Should we be using something else besides an iframe?

Help us, StackOverflow! You're our only hope!

(crossposted to some subreddits)

Comment: I don't believe this can be done without any changes to the iframed page. You would at least need some javascript embedded within that page that can communicate with the parent site.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to need 3 pages:

- Container page is the one you want have the content
- A clipping / moving page
- The page with the content

Put an iFrame on your container page. That iframe points to the clipping page. The clipping page has a  and an AJAX pull (jQuery has these) of the content page. Then then on your clipping page, the div must be moved around on its x-y axis and re-sized. This will cover the content you do not want.